# Statistics on energy mix in Europe

Tags: energy, renewable-energy

Does anybody know where to find statistics on the energy mix in Europe (preferred by country)? I can only find the share of renewables.
I'd like to see the whole mix with a split into energy sources (Wind (best case: offshore, onshore), Solar, Oil, ...) for 2020 (or the latest data available) and, if possible, also the target for, e.g., 2030.

Please point me in a direction.
Thank you!

Comment: OECD factbook may be a possibility.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Wasabi I was just about to hit post on an answer with a regularly updated resource, published by the European grid operator. For posterity, here's the link: https://transparency.entsoe.eu/generation/r2/actualGenerationPerProductionType/show

Comment: [OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are looking exactly, you probably will be able to find a lot of relevant data in the european union page for energy.

the link is [Energy Statistics an Overview](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Energy_statistics_-_an_overview#:%7E:text=Renewable%20energies%20accounted%20for%20the,renewable%20wastes%20(2.1%20%25).)